# AMFPHP how to get object in php that is dispatched by flex?

Tags: php, apache-flex, actionscript, xampp, amfphp

i am working on AMFPHP and i had this problem

-> i am using XAMPP server with AMFPHP gate way for flex and this is working well for returning values from PHP

->the problem is how can i get the object in php which i passed to the pap class using flex code is here:-

```
            connection.objectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF3;
            connection.connect("http://localhost/flashservices/gateway.php");   

            var obj:Employ = new Employ(inputs.ename.text,inputs.occu.text,inputs.adder.text,inputs.ph.text );
            var responder = new Responder(recvdata,recverror);
            connection.call("Employ.employrecord.employdata.insertrecord",responder,obj);
```

the obj is a employ class object and i want to get it in php class but how "need help"

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMFPHP will handle the heavy lifting of converting the Flash/Flex data structures into PHP equivalents. At most you should just define a service handler and provide the appropriate arguments for the method so AMF can pass the client-side data to the PHP handler.

There's a decent example of both sides of the process [here](http://flash-creations.com/notes/servercomm_remoting_amfphp.php).